# How to split text in one panda column to create new columns with delimiter as the column name

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have (made up) text in a  dataframe as follows:

```
My Hospital\r\n\r\nPatient Name MS Bilbo Baggins\r\nDate of Birth 12/11/1932\r\nHospital Number:122222D\r\nDate of Procedure 09/11/2018\r\n\r\nEndoscopist:Dr. Jonny BeGood:\r\n2nd Endoscopist:\r\nReferring Physician \r\nGeneral Practicioner Dr Gilbert Prior
```

I'd like to split the data according to delimiters so that the delimiter becomes the column name. I'd end up with

```
Raw Text                Patient Name       Date of Birth    Hospital Number   Date of Procedure:    Endoscopist:    Endoscopist:  Referring Physician :   General Practicioner:
                         MS Bilbo Baggins    12/11/1932      122222D           09/11/2018          Dr. Jonny BeGood    NA          NA                     NA
```

One tricky part is that the delimiters do not always appear in the same order but happy for that to be a second part to the answer if this is not an easy thing to solve.

As a first go I tried the following `Mydf.body_analysed.str.extract('(Patient Name.*?Date of Birth)')`

but nothing has been extracted and I suspect this is because of carriage returns which further complicates things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `series.str.extract()`

**EXPLANATION**

Regex Pattern : `f'[\n]*{c}[:]*[\r]*[\n]*([A-Za-z0-9/. ]+)[:]*[\r]*'`

- `[\n]*{c}`:  It will search for every value "c" followed by zero or more occurence of **\n**
- `[:]*[\r]*[\n]*`: zero or more occurrence of **:** , **\r**, **\n** sequentially.
- `([A-Za-z0-9/. ]+)`: Capturing desired word that can contain defined set of letters and symbols
- `[:]*[\r]*` : zero or more occurrence of **:**, **\r** after the captured word.

**Complete Code:**

```
Mydf = pd.DataFrame({"body_analysed": ["My Hospital\r\n\r\nPatient Name MS Bilbo Baggins\r\nDate of Birth 12/11/1932\r\nHospital Number:122222D\r\nDate of Procedure 09/11/2018\r\n\r\nEndoscopist:Dr. Jonny BeGood:\r\n2nd Endoscopist:\r\nReferring Physician \r\nGeneral Practicioner Dr Gilbert Prior"]})

columns = ["Patient Name","Date of Birth","Hospital Number","Date of Procedure","Hospital Number","Endoscopist","2nd Endoscopist","General Practicioner"]
for c in columns:
    Mydf[c] = Mydf["body_analysed"].str.extract(f'[\n]*{c}[:]*[\r]*[\n]*([A-Za-z0-9/. ]+)[:]*[\r]*')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
       body_analysed                                            Patient Name    Date of Birth   Hospital Number Date of Procedure   Endoscopist        2nd Endoscopist    General Practicioner
    0   My Hospital\r\n\r\nPatient Name MS Bilbo Baggi...   MS Bilbo Baggins    12/11/1932      122222D           09/11/2018        Dr. Jonny BeGood   Referring Physician  Dr Gilbert Prior
```